# Putting a link below an image

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I'm trying to put an link below an image and for whatever reason, the link just keeps going to the side (right) of the picture. The image displays fine and the link works, but I just need it underneath the picture.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="imgs/2.jpeg" width="280" height="350" alt="Exterior" />
  <a class="link1" href="https://www.google.com">Test</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images {
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

I'm new to HTML/CSS so if anyone can explain in easy terms, I would really appreciate it. I have tried lots of different things such as span, align etc and it just won't work!

If I use a p statement instead of a ULR (h ref) the text does go below the image, so I'm baffled!

Comment: The `<img>` and the `<a>` elements are the `display:inline` type, normally used in text. This is normal behaviour for this display type. You just need to change the display type of both to `display:block` or a hybrid: `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display flex to make this a column.
Explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp

```css
.images {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 120%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="imgs/2.jpeg" width="280" height="350" alt="Exterior" />
  <a class="link1" href="https://www.google.com">Test </a>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to use flexbox... `img { display: block; }` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Images are by default inline-element 8though treated as `inline-block`). All you need to do, is to set the image as block-level element with : `img { display: block; }`

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" width="280" height="350" alt="Exterior" />
  <a class="link1" href="https://www.google.com">Test </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the break line tag below the image tag.

```
<div class = "images">
<img src="imgs/2.jpeg" width="280" height="350" alt="Exterior" />
<br>
<a class="link1" href = "https://www.google.com" >Test </a>
</div>
```

Comment: wrong use of br

Comment: @tacoshy but it still works right
What is the right use of the <br> tag if I may ask?

Comment: well its not completely wrong use. however an image set to block level element has certain advantages. And as such it will be unecessary to use br to break block level elements. Espacially if you can solve styling problems with CSS it should be prefered then to use html markups

Comment: Alright, thanks man